# How to change sync frequency in Outlook app?

Tags: email, outlook

By default Outlook for Android gets the emails immediately when they are received (push).

Is there a way to set the sync frequency either individually for each email account or at least globally ?

If it matters, my email accounts are all Exchange ones.

On the stock email app (Samsung) it is possible to choose the sync frequency and even set manual syncing, but I can't find any similar option in Outlook for Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the frequency of emails sync using Outlook for Android (see the thread [Set sync frequency and quiet times on outlook app](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_amobile-mso_o365b/set-sync-frequency-and-quiet-times-on-outlook-app/344bf497-6490-4bb9-83bb-1cb5a6434e99)).

From the link above:

> There are no such settings in the Outlook or OWA apps from the play store

Outlook for Android users have requested the feature on [Uservoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/31838644-sync-settings). However, it has not been yet implemented (as of Nov. 2018).

If you are using an another app to check your Exchange emails (I use the Gmail app) then it is possible to change the sync frequency.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll change back to an app that allow to change the sync frequency then.

Comment: Maybe soon, Microsoft will listen to the users and add this important feature.

Comment: That Uservoice page is now a 404. :(

Comment: @stack Microsoft decided to shutdown their uservoice forum in 2021 https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-has-quietly-shut-down-its-office-365-uservoice-forums-more-to-come

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature has been added to the Android Outlook app: https://supertekboy.com/2018/07/21/do-not-disturb-in-outlook-mobile/

Comment: No quite. The Do not disturb is different from sync frequencies that you can set on other apps (15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, etc). If for example, you set the do not disturb for 1  hour, after it completes, incoming email will be received immediately. They will not wait for another 1 hour.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio While I acknowledge you're correct that do not disturb is different than custom sync frequency, I feel it accomplishes what many would ultimately be looking for in such a feature, which is to avoid intrusions from the app during specified times. This is what I was looking for, at least.

Comment: It's also semi-hidden in the app, not appearing in settings despite being a setting, so I was glad to find a resource to point me in the right direction.